# Download a text/csv file from django app that populates HTML table from a database query

Tags: python, mysql, django, csv, view

I currently have a django app which I can search to query my database which populates a html table from a query.

My app_home.html looks like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RESULTS APP</title>
</head>
   <form method="get" action="results/">
       <div class="SearchBar"><input type="text" name="lab_number"></div>
       <input class='input_button' type='submit'>
   </form>

<body></body>
</html>
```

This is my views.py:

```
def from_samrun(request):    
    if request.GET:
        lab_query = request.GET['lab_number']
        var_list = VarSamRun.objects.filter(sample=lab_query)
        if var_list:
            return render(request, 'results/varlist.html', {'var_list': var_list})
        else:
            return render(request, 'results/varlist.html', {'query': [sam_query]})
    else:
        return render(request, 'results/varlist.html' {'error': 'Error'})
```

which takes me to my varlist.html template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Results page</title></head>

<body>
    <div>

        {% if var_list %}

              {% for v in var_list %}

                <tr>
                <td class='varsrow' width='100'>{{v.sample}}</td>
                <td class='varsrow' width='100'>{{v.gene}}</td>
                <td class='varsrow' width='200'>{{v.variant}}</td>
                <td class='varsrow' width='150'>{{v.cds}}</td>
                <td class='varsrow' width='150'>{{v.protein}}</td>
                <td class='varsrow' width='200'>{{v.consequence}}</td>
                <td class='varsrow' width='200'>{{v.run}}</td>

                <td class='varsrow' width='300'>{{v.annotation}}</td>
                </tr>

            {% endfor %}    

      {% elif query %}

                <h5>Search using: "

                {% for q in query %}
                    {{q}}
                {% endfor %}

            " did not return any results</h5>

      {% else %}

            <h5>{{annotation}}</h5>

     {% endif %}

    </table>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

my urls are:

```
    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^results/$', views.results_app, name='results_app'),
    url(r'results/varlist/$', views.from_samrun, name='from_samrun'),
```

I want to have a download button on my varlist.html page so that when the table is displayed the user can choose to download - export to a csv file. I am aware of how to write data to a csv and download it using another view:

```
def download_view(request):
    response = HttpResponse('')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.csv'   
    writer = csv.writer(response, dialect=csv.excel)
    writer.writerow(some_random_data_list)
    return response
```

and add a form button to download to my varlist.html page:

```
<form action ='download' method='POST'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden'>
    <input type='submit' value='Download'>
</form>
```

but I have no idea how to pass the information from my first view to my download view, or pass the html table info as an object to my download view. 
(i tried passing {{var_list}} as a value in this html form, extracting the data from it and creating a new query object but this does not work for every  table as they are too large.

Is there a way to pass my var_list object from the first view to download view? How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You can put lab_query in a hidden field of your form on varlist.html, and run VarSamRun.objects.filter(sample=lab_query) again in your download view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact you are requesting the same set of data from your site. The only thing changing is the format. So normally you just want to request the same page with a GET parameter like `?format=csv`. So your view function would look like this:

```
def from_samrun(request):    
    if request.GET:
        lab_query = request.GET['lab_number']
        var_list = VarSamRun.objects.filter(sample=lab_query)
        if request.GET['format'] == 'csv':
            response = HttpResponse('')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.csv'   
            writer = csv.writer(response, dialect=csv.excel)
            writer.writerow(some_random_data_list)
            return response

        if var_list:
            return render(request, 'results/varlist.html', {'var_list': var_list,'lab_query':lab_query})
        else:
            return render(request, 'results/varlist.html', {'query': [sam_query]})
    else:
        return render(request, 'results/varlist.html' {'error': 'Error'})
```

And your template:

```
<form method='GET'>
    <input type='hidden' name='format' value='csv'>
    <input type='hidden' name='lab_query' value={{lab_query}}>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: I have thought of doing this - but this would mean I would have the download button on my query page wouldn't it? So before the user has seen the table it would produce, they would download it? I would like the user to see the table, and then click a download button at the bottom of that page (where the VarSamRun object data has been rendered)

Comment: You can check in template if var_list is set `{% if var_list %} <form>...</form> {% endif %}`

Comment: But "request.GET['lab_number']" will not return anything on this page as that GET form will have lost its data: Page 1 = search box for 'lab number' > passes 'lab number' to view... Page 2 = rendered html table based on database query using 'lab number' - there is a 'download' button at the bottom of the table... Page 3 = click download and it exports my html table to csv using different view. << How do I get 'lab number' data from page 2 > 3, as GET data will be lost?

Comment: In this case I can refer to @thierry-lathuille comment. See my edit above.

Comment: Hello, sorry, I missed that the additional lab_query is added to the render request, now I am able to obtain the initial query value and yes I can run the query again from my download view. Thanks, so simple but I did not think of it!!

Answer (score 0):

You can write `URL route` for your `download` action. Point it to `download_view` view in `urls.py`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the fastest solution will be plugin: 
[jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html)

And some easy setup for your page.